# What is the best to way to handle numbers written in different human languages?

Tags: python

When user enters `1 (Arabic numeral) or ١ (hindu numeral)` , the user should receive the same response.

In my app, I have this if statement

```
if message in ["1", "١"]:
    return("hi")
else:
    return("no")
```

But this doesn't work and users enter `١` from mobile  and they get the else statement.

Is there a way to handle different forms of numbers in python?

Comment: From a purely design perspective, you can put all the numbers having similar value in a bin, a class say. Then convert all such numbers into one single format. Use the single format for processing. It's called transformer pattern.

Comment: The comparison seems to work fine when I inputted it from the console. Are you fetching the user input from the web? In that case it might have to do with encoding of the string.

Comment: yes it's fetching it from the web. It works fine for Arabic numerals such as 9 but doesn't work for its equivalent in the hindu numeral

Comment: How are you telling python the character encoding you are using for your source file?

Answer (score 1):

one other way is to use the `ord()` function which returns an integer representing the unicode of the character.

```
print(ord("١")) # returns 1633
print(ord("1")) # returns 49

if ord(message) in [1633, 49]:
    return("hi")
else:
    return("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if str(message) in ["1", "١"]:
    return("hi")
else:
    return("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if ascii(str(msg)) in ["'1'", "'\\u0661'"]:
   return("hi")
else:
   return("no")
```